# Django API split data by unique ID

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making Django API.

I collected place and review data using crwaling program.

I want to split review data by building name(unique key), but it seems all reviews are saved together and is spread to all URL.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.
from django.utils.text import slugify

def generate_unique_slug(klass, field):
    origin_slug = slugify(field, allow_unicode=True)
    unique_slug = origin_slug
    numb = 1
    while klass.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '%s-%d' % (origin_slug, numb)
        numb += 1
    return unique_slug

class BuildingData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, allow_unicode=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    building_loc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_call = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #building_time = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.slug:  # edit
            if slugify(self.building_name, allow_unicode=True) != self.slug:
                self.slug = generate_unique_slug(BuildingData, self.building_name)
            else:  # create
                self.slug = generate_unique_slug(BuildingData, self.building_name)
            super(BuildingData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    

class ReviewData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    review_content = models.TextField()
    star_num = models.FloatField()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from crawling_data.views import ReviewListAPI
from crawling_data.views import BuildingInfoAPI

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/buildingdata/', BuildingInfoAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/buildingdata/<str:slug>/', ReviewListAPI.as_view())
]
```

**models.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import ReviewData
from .models import BuildingData
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import permissions
from .serializers import ReviewSerializer
from .serializers import BuildingSerializer
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404




class BuildingInfoAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = BuildingData.objects.all()
        serializer = BuildingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        queryset = ReviewData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

A part of crwaling program

```
if __name__=='__main__':
        for item in building_dict:
            BuildingData(building_name = item['place'], building_loc = item['location'], building_call = item['call']).save()
            #BuildingData(building_name = item['place'], building_loc = item['location'], building_call = item['call'], building_time = item['time']).save()
        for item in review_dict:
            ReviewData(building_name = item['place'], review_content = item['review'], star_num = item['rate']).save()
```

Saving code above runs when program crawled all pages.

But this code saves all reviews on the same DB.

So what I want is this

*URL : api/buildingdata/A/*

```
A building - a review
A building - b review
```

*URL : api/buildingdata/B/*

```
B building - a review
B building - b review
```

But my API looks like this

*URL : api/buildingdata/A/*

```
A building - a review
A building - b review
B building - a review
B building - b review
```

*URL : api/buildingdata/B/*

```
A building - a review
A building - b review
B building - a review
B building - b review
```

Where should I fix to split review data by building name?

Comment: Can you post the views for BuildingInfoAPI & ReviewListAPI ?

Comment: posted @PJSimpo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There looks to be two problems here. There is no ***explicit*** relationship defined between your two models and your ReviewListAPI View is accepting a slug, but doing nothing with it.

You should create a foreign key relationship between buildings and their reviews and then you can use a building's slug it to filter for reviews relevant only to that building:

You could update your ReviewData model like so:

```
class ReviewData(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(BuildingData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

```
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        queryset = ReviewData.objects.filter(building__slug=slug)
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

[Retrieving Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

[Foreign Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

This may also necessetate that you [update your serializers to reflect the relation between the objects:](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

If you dont want to make the Foreign Key relationship you could try this in your views:

```
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        building_name  =  BuildingData.objects.filter(slug=slug).values_list('building_name',flat=True)[0]
        queryset = ReviewData.objects.filter(building_name=building_name)
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here you filter the BuildingData by the slug, and return the single building name value against which you want to filter your ReviewData

Comment: It says 'Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field'

Comment: ValueError: Cannot assign occurs.
I should find which things should be added more

Comment: @T1JYH I have update my answer again to give an alternative which wont involve you changing your models.